# What does "socket" mean in Socket.io?

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io, backend

I've just started learning Socket.io and it seems pretty powerful . I just can't figure out what a socket means and the difference between "io" in the client and server side !

Comment: [Socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket) here refers to the object holding the reference to the connection that was established between the server and the client. `io` is the Socket.io library itself.

Comment: ah , that helped a bit ! thanks but I need more comprehensive answer

Comment: You should then consider a more comprehensive question. What specifically do you not understand about it? (Oh, right, you asked about the difference between client `io` and server `io`. One is the library needed at the client - that only communicates with the server - and one is the library needed at the server - which needs to accept connections from multiple clients)

Comment: Well , that seems satisfying , you can post that as an answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"socket" here is a representation of the connection between a client and the server. When you talk to the socket, the other end hears you.

There are two `io` libraries in Socket.IO: the clientside one, which is responsible for talking to the server, and the serverside one, which maintains connections to multiple clients. They are different because they execute on different architectures (node vs browser) and have different roles, and consequently have different API.

Comment: Nice ! this makes really sense !

Answer (score 1):

Think of a socket as a pipe between two points. Anything you put in on the one side, comes out the other. So, the "Socket" in socket.io refers to the underlying webSocket transport it uses to make and maintain connections, just like an old TCP Socket connection.

the "io" method of both the server and the client libraries is the initiating functions to start using the libraries. At the server io() has a subset of functions that enables you to launch a server and listen for socket connections on specified port, whereas io() in the client library has a different subset of functions to establish a client connection to a socket. They opted to give it the same name, to keep consistency between code.

Ps. 'io' refers to ON/OFF , very popular with framework type node-modules as naming mechanism

Comment: More likely Input/Output. But actually British Indian Ocean Territory.

Comment: ON/OFF - comes from the first hardware IO pins developed where you could and till this day can only switch/read it on or off, but in relation to software frameworks, I get your point with regards to input/output.